# Error to add features to REST Service in Arcgis

Tags: rest, arcgis

I'm trying to add features to a layer in the REST Service of ArcGis but I got an error.

You can see the layer here: https://www.acueducto.com.co/wassigue5/arcgis/rest/services/SGO2018/Avisos/FeatureServer/0

POST Data send (I tried to put all data with null or some value but that doesn't seem to work):

```
[{
"geometry": {"x": 4.6198349, "y": -74.0754059},
"attributes": {
"NOTIF_NO_": "123456789012"
}
}]
```

Returned:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Unable to complete operation.",
  "details": [  
  ]
 }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That feature service is no longer there, or maybe it is not shared with everyone. Can you please either correct the URL or share the service with everyone?